# What's the word for a room for bath only?

Tags: word-request

In my house, there is a room with a shower but no toilet. It's for bath. You can't poop here. (Of course, you can pee here since there's drains, it's just the cleaning job is inconvenient.)

So you see, it's not intended for the call of nature. What's the proper word for this room? I don't think 'bathroom' is suitable, because it usually means 'toilet' and using it would lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of 'bathroom' in a dictionary?

Comment: I have. 'Bathroom': "noun. 1. a room equipped for taking a bath or shower. 2. toilet". From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bathroom). How does a definition like this not answer your question? (I'm merely asking for more details :)

Comment: 'Bathroom'  only means 'toilet' as well in American English.

Comment: I believe that in America a room with a shower and sink is called a 'shower room' and if there is only a shower it can be called a 'shower stall'. It seems that for many Americans, 'bathroom' now means what British speakers vulgarly call the 'toilet'.

Comment: Not forgetting Archie Bunker, who was quite happy to say 'turlet'.

Comment: My mother's family was 'respectable working class', and, I am afraid, somewhat anxious about saying the 'genteel' or 'refined' words for things, thus 'toilet', 'serviette', etc. My father was solidly middle class and had no qualms about boldly saying 'LAVATORY'. Also the cloth on the table was a 'napkin' to him.

Comment: The English word to designate a place to urinate/defecate has evolved, as each word has assumed the odour of its purpose: convenience, lavatory, latrine, privy, toilet, loo, washroom, jakes (in Australia), the head (boats), urinal, cloakroom and more that others could name.

Comment: I call ours a _shower room_ (BrE). What else would you call it?

Comment: @mdewey I will call it a *shower room* from now on, based on the comments. XD  I'm not a native speaker. : )

Comment: You may want to say "shower only" and not mention "bath". Bathing usually refers to soaking in a tub filled with water; and _bath_ can mean a _bathtub_. If there isn't a bathtub, you can just say _shower_ in your question; used both as a noun and a verb.

Comment: @Michael - Be aware that bathroom references vary greatly between British and American English.  What you may be calling some combination of shower, bath, and toilette in London, might be called something entirely different in L.A.  Probably best to call these rooms whatever the *locals* call them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about rooms in a house, as you stated, the **bathroom** contains the shower, regardless of whether it has a toilet.

If there's a separate room with just a toilet, it might be called the **commode** or perhaps even the **toilet**. But the room with the shower is always the **bathroom** (bath = bathing).

Comment: And if in doubt you say "a bathroom with no toilet" or "a room with a bath and sink but no toilet". There isn't a word for every possible combination of furniture/fittings.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this.  When I ask someone where the bathroom is, I am never interested in finding a shower stall or a bathtub.  If you sent me to a room with only a shower stall, I would have to come back and say, *I need a toilette.*  I think *shower room* is better for a room with only a shower.

Comment: We're talking about rooms in a house. In the United States, it's very uncommon to have this arrangement, although I have a friend who has exactly this setup.  The place where you bathe, in the bathtub or the shower is the bathroom. The place where you urinate is the toilet or commode. At least that's the lingo we use.

Comment: If you were a real estate agent and you were showing the house, you would say, "This is the bathroom, and there's a separate toilet. You wouldn't point to the (much smaller) toilet and say this is the bathroom and there's a separate shower (in the much larger room with the sink, etc.).

Comment: I understand the realty naming conventions.  Those are what realtors use.  Maybe if Michael begins a career in realty, your naming standard will be helpful.  But if he needs to *use the bathroom* your naming standard won't be much help.   Bathroom is a room I can *go to the bathroom* in, meaning pee most often.  If I ask you where your bathroom is, **I am not planning on bathing**.  A room with one shower stall in it is not a bathroom by that definition.

Comment: I think if his host has the unusual configuration of a toilet by itself, the host will recognize that and adjust his answer or instructions accordingly. He might even proactively tell everyone that there's a separate toilet and where it's located. Some people are smart that way.